# Update d3 chart with react props on componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, data-visualization

So, I have a d3 react component and there are a few things that I would like to change about it. But I'm having a hard time. Specifically with controlling the d3 via updating props without having to redraw the graph. Here's the code:

```
function createChart(dom, props){
    // var node = d3.select(dom);

    //Remove prev pie chart before drawing new one
    d3.select('#pie').remove();

    var input = d3.selectAll("input")

    var initMeasure = input[0].map(x => {if (x.checked){return(x.value)}})[0]

    var root = props.data

    var width = props.width,
        height = props.height,
        radius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2) - 20;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

    var y = d3.scale.sqrt()
        .range([0, radius]);

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var tooltip = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
        .attr("id", "tooltip")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("z-index", "10")
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .on("mouseover", mouseOutArc);

    function format_number(x) {
        x = x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        return x
    }


    function format_description(d) {
        var description = d.description;
        return  '<b>' + d.key + '</b></br>'+ '(' + format_number(d.value) + ')';
    }

    function computeTextRotation(d) {
        var angle=(d.x +d.dx/2)*180/Math.PI - 90

        return angle;
    }

    function mouseOverArc(d) {
        d3.select(this).attr("stroke","black")

        tooltip.html(format_description(d));
        return tooltip.transition()
            .duration(50)
            .style("opacity", 0.9);
    }

    function mouseOutArc(){
        d3.select(this).attr("stroke","grey")
        return tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
    }

    function mouseMoveArc (d) {
        return tooltip
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px")
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");
    }

    var root_ = null;

    var svg = d3.select(dom).append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("id", 'pie')
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height / 2 + 10) + ")");

    var initvalue
    switch(initMeasure) {
        case 'dollars':
            initvalue = function(d) { return d.dollars; };
            break;
        case 'units':
            initvalue = function(d) { return d.units; };
            break;
        case 'tdps':
            initvalue = function(d) { return d.tdps; };
            break;
    }

    var partition = d3.layout.partition()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) { return d.dollars; })
        .children(function(d) {return d.values});

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
        .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx))); })
        .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y)); })
        .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)); });

// Keep track of the node that is currently being displayed as the root.
    var node;

    node = root;
    var path = svg.datum(root).selectAll("path")
        .data(partition.nodes)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("id", "arc")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.values ? d : d.parent).key); })
        .attr("stroke","grey")
        .transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTweenData)
        .on("click", click)
        .on("mouseover", mouseOverArc)
        .on("mousemove", mouseMoveArc)
        .on("mouseout", mouseOutArc)
        .each(stash);

    d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change() {
        if (this.name === 'measurement') {
            var value
            switch(this.value) {
                case 'dollars':
                    value = function(d) {return d.dollars};
                    break;
                case 'units':
                    value = function(d) {return d.units};
                    break;
                case 'tdps':
                    value = function(d) {return d.tdps};
                    break;
            }
        }
        path
            .data(partition.value(value).nodes)
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attrTween("d", arcTweenData);
    });

    function click(d) {
        node = d;
        path.transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attrTween("d", arcTweenZoom(d));
        console.log('clicked: ', d.key)
    }

    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

// Setup for switching data: stash the old values for transition.
    function stash(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.dx0 = d.dx;
    }

// When switching data: interpolate the arcs in data space.
    function arcTweenData(a, i) {
        var oi = d3.interpolate({x: a.x0, dx: a.dx0}, a);
        function tween(t) {
            var b = oi(t);
            a.x0 = b.x;
            a.dx0 = b.dx;
            return arc(b);
        }
        if (i == 0) {
            // If we are on the first arc, adjust the x domain to match the root node
            // at the current zoom level. (We only need to do this once.)
            var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [node.x, node.x + node.dx]);
            return function(t) {
                x.domain(xd(t));
                return tween(t);
            };
        } else {
            return tween;
        }
    }

// When zooming: interpolate the scales.
    function arcTweenZoom(d) {
        var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
            yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
            yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
        return function(d, i) {
            return i
                ? function(t) { return arc(d); }
                : function(t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); return arc(d); };
        };
    }

};

@observer
class SunburstChart extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var dom =  ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
        createChart(dom, this.props);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(x) {
        console.log('props received: ', x)
        var dom =  ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
        createChart(dom, x);

    }


    render() {
        console.log('sunburst chart rendered: ')
        return (
            <div>
                <RadioButtonGroup name="measurement" defaultSelected="dollars">
                    <RadioButton
                        value="dollars"
                        label="Dollars"
                    />
                    <RadioButton
                        value="units"
                        label="Units"
                    />
                    <RadioButton
                        value="tdps"
                        label="Tdps"
                    />
                </RadioButtonGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

When the component receives props I currently redraw the chart. However, I would love to be able to just *alter* the existing chart. If that isn't possible it would be great to have some transitions on the initial load of the chart.

Also; that line of code that looks at the input:

```
d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change() {
        if (this.name === 'measurement') {
            var value
            switch(this.value) {
                case 'dollars':
                    value = function(d) {return d.dollars};
                    break;
                case 'units':
                    value = function(d) {return d.units};
                    break;
                case 'tdps':
                    value = function(d) {return d.tdps};
                    break;
            }
        }
        path
            .data(partition.value(value).nodes)
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attrTween("d", arcTweenData);
    });
```

It would be great if I could pass that and control it through props, as well.

Any advice is greatly appreciated! Thanks for reading!

Comment: I'm also stuck by this problem. May I know your final solution?

Answer (score -1):

I'll answer 1. Question.

Here is an idea:

1. Render pie chart initially with the code as you do (so that d3 generates svg element with id you provide)
2. Create update function for piechart (see d3 thinking with joins) and when component receives new props execute that function without removing piechart from the dom but only select existing svg with id you know and instruct d3 to change svg dom attributes for (insert, update - d3 sets)

Comment: That's my thought, exactly. I'm having a pretty hard time doing that without having to re-render the chart, though.